# Why localhost not loading even after node server and mongodb loaded?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I've started learning on MEAN development. I had setup my express server and also my mongodb connection. On running `node server` in terminal the server starts running and also the mongo was able to connect but the `localhost:8081/api/videos` is not loading. I cleared cache and cookies but still no solution. I am attaching the code below.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

// Port for express server
const port = 8081;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist/mean')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/mean/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server running at localhost:' + port);
});
```

**api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Video = require('../models/video');

// Creating mongo db connection
const db = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@training-qfjgb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(db, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, err => {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Error: '+err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Successfully connected to mongodb');
    }
  });

router.get('/videos', function(req, res){
    console.log('Get request for all videos');
    Video.find({}).exec(function(err, videos){
      if(err)
      {console.log('Error retrieving videos');}
      else
      {res.json(videos);}
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**video.js** (This is for the schema)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Creating database schema

const videoSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    url: String,
    description: String
});

// Creating model of database videoplayer as model and then exporting
module.exports = mongoose.model('video', videoSchema, 'videoplayer');
```

Comment: How do you know "localhost isn't loading?" Did you use `http://localhost:8081/videos/`? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones yes I've done

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@training-qfjgb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```

username:password should be changed.
admin:12345(as you using)

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@training-qfjgb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```

Check this part thoroughly , Whether the collection name, format of the text are given correctly